# Argument of [object Object] passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo

I am getting this error:

*"Invariant Violation: Argument of [object Object] passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document"*

when I try to use **useQuery** from **@apollo/client**

```html
import categoriesQuery from "@/gqlQueries/categories";
import {useQuery} from "@apollo/client";

const CategoryProduct = ({ updateProductCategory }) => {
    const data = useQuery(categoriesQuery)
    //something
}
```

This is my query and when I use that for example in `getStaticProps` it works ok

```html
import {gql} from "@apollo/client";

const categoriesQuery = {
    query: gql`
        query {
            mainPage(id:"5wrEkvwy8F87kF5d6WQxCL") {
                featuredCategoriesCollection {
                    items {
                        metaTitle
                        metaDescription
                        title
                        description
                        image {
                            url
                        }
                        bg
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `
};

export default categoriesQuery;
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG58l.png)

Comment: as docs said you must use result of `gql` tag, so try change to this `const data = useQuery(categoriesQuery.result)`

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `useQuery` should be the `DocumentNode` returned by `gql`.

Therefore, the following will do the trick:

```
const data = useQuery(categoriesQuery.query)
```

See the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#function-signature) for more details.